# DataTables for ASP.NET column sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I'm using DataTables Serverside processing with Web API using this [DataTables ASP.NET](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet).  It works good but I want to find a better way to handle the sorting in the `APIController` methods. Right now I'm using a lot of `if statements` and referencing the `IDataTablesRequest.Column` field name explicitly but I'll have to do this for every field and table. My code below is inside my `APIController` method called by `datatables` using ajax get.  The `request` object in the code is a `IDataTablesRequest` request from [DataTables ASP.NET](https://github.com/ALMMa/datatables.aspnet).  The sort column is sent in this.

I've looked into using an `IEnumerable` extension method on `SortBy<>` but it didn't work from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691900/sorting-a-datatable-using-linq-when-sort-by-columns-may-vary) .

This is the code I use to sort right now.  Is there a better way to handle this that doesn't need to explicitly use field names so it can sort by any field sent?

```
var orderColums = request.Columns.Where(x => x.Sort != null);

var filteredData = deviceList.Where(_item => _item.UserName.Contains(request.Search.Value));

IColumn sortColumn = orderColums.FirstOrDefault();
var dataPage = new object();
if (sortColumn != null && sortColumn.Field == "dateCreated")
{
    if (sortColumn.Sort.Direction == DataTables.AspNet.Core.SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dataPage = filteredData.OrderBy(o => o.DateCreated).Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        dataPage = filteredData.OrderByDescending(o => o.DateCreated).Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);
    }
}
else if (sortColumn != null && sortColumn.Field == "userName") 
{
    if (sortColumn.Sort.Direction == DataTables.AspNet.Core.SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
    dataPage = filteredData.OrderBy(o => o.UserName).Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        dataPage = filteredData.OrderByDescending(o => o.UserName).Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);
    }
}
else 
{
    dataPage = filteredData.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your columns without knowing the field names by using [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection). Here is an example using your code:

```
var orderColums = request.Columns.Where(x => x.Sort != null);

var filteredData = deviceList.Where(_item => _item.UserName.Contains(request.Search.Value));

IColumn sortColumn = orderColums.FirstOrDefault();
string newField = "";
// Change first character to match column name
newField += sortColumn.Field.ToUpper().First() + string.Join("", sortColumn.Field.Skip(1));
var dataPage = new object();
if (sortColumn != null)
{
    if (sortColumn.Sort.Direction == DataTables.AspNet.Core.SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dataPage = filteredData.OrderBy(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(newField).GetValue(o))
            .Skip(request.Start)
            .Take(request.Length);
    }
    else
    {
        dataPage = filteredData.OrderByDescending(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(newField).GetValue(o))
            .Skip(request.Start)
            .Take(request.Length);
    }
}
else
{
    dataPage = filteredData.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length);
}
```